# Exporting Excel file from PHP spread sheet. when I add certain amount of "Echo" , weird string output show up and won't export

Tags: php, sql, excel

I have this code it works well to export excel file, However, when I try to add more `Echo"zzzz"`; it shows weird strings such as

> '��vAa    �(0����ؖg�w{&i�@�nbE�{��y��d۸l
>   m�����X�(���)���F��;@1_�����c)j�x/%��E��y�
>   _rels/.rels���j�0��{ �{���1F�^ʠ�2��l�$'

and won't export. It only occurs when I add so many Echo ""; statements with bunch of different output.

```
<?php include'db.php';
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
echo"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";

$spreadsheet2 = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet2->getActiveSheet();
$sheet-> setCellValue('A1','a');


$filename2 ='sample'.time().'.xlsx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename2 .'"'); 
/*-- $filename is  xsl filename ---*/
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

ob_end_clean();


$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet2);
$writer->save('php://output');

}
}

?>
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how to prevent it?

Comment: Look at the HTTP response headers. Explain the purpose of `ob_end_clean()`.

Comment: 1. Because you don't have `error_reporting` turned out which would otherwise be shouting relevant errors at you. 2. Because don't do that. Why in the world are you doing that?

Comment: If you want to export a binary file like this you must not output any additional characters using echo, or you will invalidate the file format. Only use the `$sheet` methods to write on the spreadsheet.